# Can't run npm install on Ubuntu 20.4 server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I have a node.js application that I want to run on an Ubuntu 20.4 server, when I try to run the command npm install, I see the following error, I do not have root access on the server, where can this problem be? I have version 6.14.3 of npm and version 14.15.3, how can i deal with this problem?

````js
```
npm WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /var/www/site/public_html/node_modules/@nuxt/babel-preset-app/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

Thank you for using core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock/core-js ) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library!

The project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon:
> https://opencollective.com/core-js
> https://www.patreon.com/zloirock

Also, the author of core-js ( https://github.com/zloirock ) is looking for a good job -)


> core-js@3.10.2 postinstall /var/www/site/public_html/node_modules/core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> bootstrap-vue@2.21.2 postinstall /var/www/site/public_html/node_modules/bootstrap-vue
> opencollective || exit 0

sh: 1: opencollective: Permission denied

> nuxt@2.15.4 postinstall /var/www/site/public_html/node_modules/nuxt
> opencollective || exit 0

sh: 1: opencollective: Permission denied

> swiper@5.4.5 postinstall /var/www/site/public_html/node_modules/swiper
> echo "Love Swiper? Support Vladimir's work by donating or pledging on patreon:
 > https://patreon.com/vladimirkharlampidi
"

Love Swiper? Support Vladimir's work by donating or pledging on patreon:
 > https://patreon.com/vladimirkharlampidi

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

added 1334 packages from 697 contributors and audited 1338 packages in 17.59s

102 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 58 vulnerabilities (39 moderate, 18 high, 1 critical)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might have the issue with permission
Try this

```html
sudo npm cache clean 
sudo npm install
```